# How to compare contents of columns in Excel without regard for what row the data is on?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have 345 columns with names in each of them. I would like to find a way to pick a column (currently have a drop-down on a separate sheet to make that selection), then find the rest of the columns that contain at least one of the entries in the selected column and list them. For example, I would like to be able to select Col A in this sample:

[image: Sample]

and have a list returned with Col B and Col D in it on the sheet with the drop-down selection.

Everything I have found only matches entries that are on the same row and would only return Col D in the sample.

Comment: What do you mean by "returned"? You want to see the names in a modal window? You want to see a new worksheet with just those columns? You want to see those columns highlighted a certain color and focused, in their existing worksheet?

Comment: If I can get the column names listed on the sheet with the drop-down lists, that would be great. I'll edit the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

this code uses regex to match the names. so you have to enable regex under extras --> references and select "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5". (read more about [RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops))

```
Sub MatchNames(col As Range, ws as Worksheet)
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim exp As String: exp = "(" & Join(Application.Transpose(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, col.Column), ws.Cells(lRow, 1))), "|") & ")"
exp = Replace(exp, " ", "")

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = exp
End With
Dim matched As String
For i = 1 To lCol
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim data As String: data = Join(Application.Transpose(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(lRow, i))), ";")
    data = Replace(data, " ", "")
    If regEx.Test(data) Then
        matched = matched & ws.Cells(1, i).Value & ";"
    End If
Next i
MsgBox ("Matched Columns:" & vbNewLine & Replace(matched, ";", vbNewLine))
End Sub
```

The parameters are any cell of the column with the names to match and the worksheet the data is in, i.e `Call MatchNames(Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1), Worksheets(1))` to match `Col A` on worksheet 1. it will then return a message box with all columns that had a match. What it basically does is to create a pattern with all names of that column and this will be matched with a joined string of all cells of column to match. As it only takes n steps for n columns the runtime should be pretty good aswell for all sizes of data.

Comment: Small improvement: there is no need for the `ws` parameter.  Use `col.Worksheet` instead.